# How to generate Notification for android project with minSdkVersion="8" and targetSdkVersion="17"

Tags: android, android-notifications

i am trying to generate notification. here i am facing problem with deprecated method for higher API level and when i am going to use Notification.Builder() then it gives error that 
Call requires API level 11

here is my code

```
public void generateNotification(Context context, String message,String id) {
        int icon = R.drawable.notiIcon;
        String title = context.getString(R.string.app_name);

        long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification;

            notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,
                    NotificationViewActivity.class);
            notificationIntent.putExtra("msg",  message);
            // set intent so it does not start a new activity
            notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                    | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                    notificationIntent, 0);
            notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message,
                    intent);
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;



                      //here i have Notification.Builder ... that gives error API leve 
            /*
                        notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
                    .setContentTitle(title).setContentText(message)
                    .setSmallIcon(icon).build();
                         */
        notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
    }
```

how to resolve this problem .. because i require min version 8 and target 17.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [NotificationCompat.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/NotificationCompat.Builder.html) instead. From the standard support library v4.

By the way, the `targetSdkVersion` is not a problematic parameter in most of situations, no need to specify it in this problem. Just try to use the latest API all the time (and currently is 19).

Answer (score -1):

There's nothing wrong with using deprecated methods, no harm in that. 
Also, you can differentiate between the SDK levels with

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 10) {

}

else {

}
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using deprecated methods if you check that you are using those methods on a version of the SDK that still supports them. The methods could be removed in future versions so your app could stop working on future versions of Android. (btw, the downvote was not me)

Comment: thanks ascorbin.. something like this i had tried but it gives error in else part.. ok,  NotificationCompat.Builder solves the problem. thanks for your reply..